# How do I know I properly setup SciTE for ConTeXt?

Tags: context, editors

I am trying to setup SciTE to have an handful GTK editor on Debian for **ConTeXt**. I think I correctly followed the steps however I don't see any change...

Documentation says:

> while on linux you get:
>
> `/usr/bin/share/`
> `/usr/bin/share/context`
> `/usr/bin/share/context/lexer`
> `/usr/bin/share/context/lexer/themes`
> `/usr/bin/share/context/lexer/data`
> `/usr/bin/share/context/documents`
>
> At the end of the `SciteGlobal.properties` you need to add the following line:
>
> `import context/scite-context-user`
>
> After this, things should run as expected (given that TEX runs at the console as well).

Thus I basically ran these commands:

```
sudo echo "import context/scite-context-user" >> /etc/scite/SciTEGlobal.properties
sudo mkdir /usr/bin/share/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/texmf/context/data/scite/context/ /usr/bin/share
```

And when I check inside the directory suggested I can see the right files:

```
ls /usr/bin/share/context/
documents/
lexers/
scite-context-data-context.properties
scite-context-data-interfaces.properties
scite-context-data-metafun.properties
scite-context-data-metapost.properties
scite-context-data-tex.properties
scite-context-external.properties
scite-context-internal.properties
scite-context.properties
scite-context-user.properties
scite-ctx-bidi.lua
scite-ctx-context.properties
scite-ctx-example.properties
scite-ctx.lua
scite-ctx.properties
scite-ctx-templates.lua
scite-metapost.properties
scite-pragma.properties
scite-tex.properties
```

However looks like nothing has changed, I know this is a pebcak but I don't have idea which one it is... :(

Thanks,

F.

Comment: `/usr/bin/share/` is a really bizarre path to use. The manual says to use that path, but it's really weird to have any subdirectories in `/usr/bin`. Maybe try using `/usr/share/` instead of  `/usr/bin/share/`? (completely untested)

Comment: I tried to put these files in `/etc/scite/` and `~/.scite` ; `~/.config/scite` ; `~/.local/share/scite` also chaging `import context/scite-context-user` using the aforementioned path but it didn't work the same...

Comment: **SOLVED:** the right path is: `/usr/share/scite` I copied all the files in there and the layout actually changed!

Comment: Good to hear that that fixed it. You should post that as an answer for any future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like I found the answer by myself... ^^'

The files are located in `/usr/share/texmf/context/data/scite/context/`
while the right directory to copy those files into, is: `/usr/share/scite`

Eventually I did everything manually with `mc` but the commands might be:

```
sudo cp -R /usr/share/texmf/context/data/scite/context/ /usr/share/scite
sudo echo "import context/scite-context-user" >> /etc/scite/SciTEGlobal.properties
```

The weird thing is all the files already available in `/usr/share/scite` are *symlinks* to `/etc/scite/`:

```
abaqus.properties -> /etc/scite/abaqus.properties
abbrev.properties -> /etc/scite/abbrev.properties
ada.properties -> /etc/scite/ada.properties
asciidoc.properties -> /etc/scite/asciidoc.properties
asl.properties -> /etc/scite/asl.properties
asm.properties -> /etc/scite/asm.properties
asn1.properties -> /etc/scite/asn1.properties
au3.properties -> /etc/scite/au3.properties
ave.properties -> /etc/scite/ave.properties
avs.properties -> /etc/scite/avs.properties
baan.properties -> /etc/scite/baan.properties
blitzbasic.properties -> /etc/scite/blitzbasic.properties
bullant.properties -> /etc/scite/bullant.properties
caml.properties -> /etc/scite/caml.properties
cil.properties -> /etc/scite/cil.properties
cmake.properties -> /etc/scite/cmake.properties
cobol.properties -> /etc/scite/cobol.properties
coffeescript.properties -> /etc/scite/coffeescript.properties
conf.properties -> /etc/scite/conf.properties
cpp.properties -> /etc/scite/cpp.properties
csound.properties -> /etc/scite/csound.properties
css.properties -> /etc/scite/css.properties
dataflex.properties -> /etc/scite/dataflex.properties
d.properties -> /etc/scite/d.properties
ecl.properties -> /etc/scite/ecl.properties
eiffel.properties -> /etc/scite/eiffel.properties
Embedded.properties -> /etc/scite/Embedded.properties
erlang.properties -> /etc/scite/erlang.properties
escript.properties -> /etc/scite/escript.properties
flagship.properties -> /etc/scite/flagship.properties
forth.properties -> /etc/scite/forth.properties
fortran.properties -> /etc/scite/fortran.properties
freebasic.properties -> /etc/scite/freebasic.properties
fsharp.properties -> /etc/scite/fsharp.properties
gap.properties -> /etc/scite/gap.properties
haskell.properties -> /etc/scite/haskell.properties
hex.properties -> /etc/scite/hex.properties
html.properties -> /etc/scite/html.properties
inno.properties -> /etc/scite/inno.properties
json.properties -> /etc/scite/json.properties
kix.properties -> /etc/scite/kix.properties
latex.properties -> /etc/scite/latex.properties
lisp.properties -> /etc/scite/lisp.properties
lot.properties -> /etc/scite/lot.properties
lout.properties -> /etc/scite/lout.properties
lua.properties -> /etc/scite/lua.properties
markdown.properties -> /etc/scite/markdown.properties
matlab.properties -> /etc/scite/matlab.properties
maxima.properties -> /etc/scite/maxima.properties
metapost.properties -> /etc/scite/metapost.properties
mmixal.properties -> /etc/scite/mmixal.properties
modula3.properties -> /etc/scite/modula3.properties
nim.properties -> /etc/scite/nim.properties
nimrod.properties -> /etc/scite/nimrod.properties
nncrontab.properties -> /etc/scite/nncrontab.properties
nsis.properties -> /etc/scite/nsis.properties
opal.properties -> /etc/scite/opal.properties
oscript.properties -> /etc/scite/oscript.properties
others.properties -> /etc/scite/others.properties
pascal.properties -> /etc/scite/pascal.properties
perl.properties -> /etc/scite/perl.properties
pov.properties -> /etc/scite/pov.properties
powerpro.properties -> /etc/scite/powerpro.properties
powershell.properties -> /etc/scite/powershell.properties
ps.properties -> /etc/scite/ps.properties
purebasic.properties -> /etc/scite/purebasic.properties
python.properties -> /etc/scite/python.properties
raku.properties -> /etc/scite/raku.properties
rebol.properties -> /etc/scite/rebol.properties
registry.properties -> /etc/scite/registry.properties
r.properties -> /etc/scite/r.properties
ruby.properties -> /etc/scite/ruby.properties
rust.properties -> /etc/scite/rust.properties
sas.properties -> /etc/scite/sas.properties
33 Dec  7 08:10 SciTEGlobal.properties -> /etc/scite/SciTEGlobal.properties
SciTE.properties -> /etc/scite/SciTE.properties
scriptol.properties -> /etc/scite/scriptol.properties
smalltalk.properties -> /etc/scite/smalltalk.properties
sorcins.properties -> /etc/scite/sorcins.properties
specman.properties -> /etc/scite/specman.properties
spice.properties -> /etc/scite/spice.properties
sql.properties -> /etc/scite/sql.properties
tacl.properties -> /etc/scite/tacl.properties
tal.properties -> /etc/scite/tal.properties
tcl.properties -> /etc/scite/tcl.properties
tex.properties -> /etc/scite/tex.properties
txt2tags.properties -> /etc/scite/txt2tags.properties
vb.properties -> /etc/scite/vb.properties
verilog.properties -> /etc/scite/verilog.properties
vhdl.properties -> /etc/scite/vhdl.properties
visualprolog.properties -> /etc/scite/visualprolog.properties
yaml.properties -> /etc/scite/yaml.properties
```

However copy the files into that directory didn't work as well as in:

- `~/.scite`
- `~/.config/scite/`
- `~/.local/share/`

Personally I found the UI/UX even more confused and I think I am going to use `TexWorks` even though I really dislike QT applications... :/